# Shadow issues on rotation

Tags: animation, light, lighting, shadows

I have a rotating in a blender file with a single plane as ground. The object rotates find and the shadow is casted correctly onto the plane, but the shadows of the rotating object itself do something very annoying: they kind of "snap", it doesn't look natural.

It's also on only some places on the object that this happens, on all the other parts it does look natural and normal. I'll upload a short animation here to show the issue.

You can see that when the object rotates, most parts cast their shadow normal but this one part is very obviously "snappy":
[image]

I'm using the cycles engine, 60fps, 128 samples and no denoiser (not yet final product). Changing the framerate did not solve the issue, at 120 fps (way to much for my goal) this was still issue was still present.

Also changing the sample count did not really help, but there was visible difference. But once I go over 128 samples it seems to not change the effect anymore, it stays like in the gif no matter how high I put the sample count.

Is this a known issue and is there a way to solve it? I really don't know what I can do more to avoid this.

I've also changed the light source and resized it etc etc, it does **change** the issue but the snapping stays, it's just a bit shorter or a bit later but it still snaps, no matter what I do.

Comment: This is strange.. could you share the file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: I will add it to this questions once I can. The current blend file is one I cannot share unfortunately but I will recreate the issue and upload that .blend.

Comment: Is this object pretty low poly count?  Is this illuminated by a point light?

Comment: @AllenSimpson yes and yes.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating it but my suspicion is a topological problem and/or maybe an individual face is set to a different shading mode.  Are you using shade smooth or autosmooth?

Comment: @AllenSimpson The mesh is made out of (previously) seperated and then joined meshes, when they were all joined I applied subsurface and shade smooth;

Answer (score 0):

I had, and corrected a nearly identical issue moments ago. The problem was that I had overlooked marking one edge of my low poly model as sharp, causing it to render correctly from most angles but the shadows to snap when tweening under lighting.
Hope this helps.